# Validação automática e em tempo real de cada Text field

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu quero que cada `TextFormField` seja validado individualmente e em tempo real conforme o usuário vai digitando, consegui esse comportamento usando `TextEditingController` e atualizando o `errorText` de cada `TextFormField` conforme valido o texto do `controller`.
Contudo, fazer dessa forma me parece 'gambiarra', uma vez que cada `TextFormField` possui seu parâmetro `validator` e existe o Form com o `autovalidateMode` - agora que o `autovalidade` foi descontinuado.
Tentando usar o que citei a cima não consigo o comportamento desejado, o mais próximo que chego é usando

`autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction`

e obtenho como resultado todos os campos atualizados de uma vez com a mensagem de validação apos a interação do usuário com qualquer campo.

A 1° forma que fiz já é a correta ou é possível o comportamento que desejo com a 2°?

Answer (score 1):

Você não forneceu um exemplo, mas esse seu problema ocorre pois o texto inicial de cada `TextFormField` (provavelmente um texto vazio) já faz a validação retornar como falsa. Então, em um estado inicial, todos os `TextFormField` podem ser considerados como não-validados.

> [...] uma vez que cada TextFormField possui seu parâmetro validator e existe o Form com o autovalidateMode [...]

Não apenas o [Form](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html) possui a propriedade `autovalidadeMode`. Cada [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) individualmente também pode ter essa propriedade configurada.

Experimente remover essa property do `Form` e colocar diretamente em cada TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        validator: (String value) {
                               return value.contains('') ? 'Validação do erro' : null;
                        },
              )
```

O seguinte exemplo, adaptado livremente da página da documentação acima, demonstra o resultado desejado (Pode ser testado no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/)):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Examplo TextFormField',
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: Form(
          child: Wrap(
            children: List<Widget>.generate(5, (int index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(const Size(200, 50)),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    validator: (String value) {
                      return value.contains('')
                          ? 'Validação que retorna falsa no valor inicial.'
                          : null;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```